# How to modify the existing PDF in Android

Tags: android

I already shown a PDF file in android device. But I need to scribble (writing with my finger) in that PDF page and I need to save the changes with existing PDF file itself in the sdcard. I searched so many source codes but i can't get what i am expected. Could you anyone help me on this. Thanks.

Comment: Try Radaee pdf. It does

Comment: Thanks Mohammed Imran, while i open the page which contains watermark as Radaee, how do i take this watermark. please give your suggestion.

Comment: You cant take unless u buy licence

Comment: any alternate solution is there, because the licence cost is too high.